# MySQL Dump - meta queries

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL dump file that is not loading, the issue seems to be about:

```
ERROR 1231 (42000) at line 11: Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
```

Looking at the dump file- it shows the CREATE table statement and this line:

```
*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

I cannot find any documentation that discusses this kind of commented-code in MySQL dump files. Anyone got any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments starting with `/*!` are MySQL-specific SQL statements that are still executed by MySQL but ignored by other SQL databases. For reference see the MySQL docs on [comments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comments.html).

In your case, it seems like the `@saved_cs_client` is `NULL`, which is not a valid value for `character_set_client`. You could set `@saved_cs_client`, or modify the line to set `character_set_client` to the character set that you use.

(Btw. I would recommend to always use `utf8mb4` as your character set.)